# Why doesn't race condition occur?

Tags: c, multithreading, race-condition

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define SIZE 2 /* array size */
#define NUM_THREADS 2

int max_num = 0;

int list[SIZE] = {1, 2};

void print_list(void);
void* runner(void* param);
void parallel_find_max_num(void);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  parallel_find_max_num();

  return 0;
}

void* runner(void* param)
{
  int part = *(int *)param;
  int size = SIZE / NUM_THREADS;
  int start_idx = part * size;

  if(part == NUM_THREADS - 1)
    size += SIZE % NUM_THREADS;

  /* update max num */
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if(max_num < list[start_idx + i])
      max_num = list[start_idx + i];
}

void parallel_find_max_num(void)
{
  pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
  int param[2]= {0, 1};

  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, runner, &param[i]);
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);

  printf("Max Number = %d\n", max_num);
}
```

I expected a race condition to occur, but it doesn't.

Expected result: Max Number = 1

I think there should be problems when threads write to the shared resource max_num at the same time.
<s>However, there has never been a case where max_num has 1. max_num always has 2.</s>

I found that max_num has 1 in about 90000th run.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Race conditions leads to *undefined behavior*. Sometimes undefined behavior will seem to work. Sometimes it will not. And sometimes it will summon [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) or set your cat on fire. So just because you don't see anything special when running your code, it will still have a race condition and undefined behavior. What did you actually expect to happen?

Comment: Just because a race condition *exists* it doesn't necessarily mean that it actually is triggered! You get into trouble if one of the thread updates `max_num` right in between the other thread having read (`max_num < ...`) and going to write (`max_num = ...`) – then the interrupted thread relies on stale data. However thread creation takes some time – it is pretty likely the first thread has already performed all of its tasks while second one is not even yet running, but still constructed... This doesn't change anything about the UB, though.

Comment: It can also be **very** difficult to actually trigger a race condition and observe any failure.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that it likely takes much longer to request and allocate a thread from the OS than it takes to run your callback. So each thread might finish long before the next is created. Create all threads suspended, then enable them once all are created.

Also there *is* no race condition if you pass an individual parameter to each thread  `&param[i]`. They have to use the same data for that to apply.

Also your thread callback has a different form of undefined behavior because you didn't write a return statement in a function with a return type. As was told to you by the compiler.